# Facing Issue With HttpStatus in spring boot 3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http-status-codes

Currently i am working on a project to upgrade it to spring boot 3 ,spring 6.x , java 17 .BUt i am facing an issue with "HttpStatus".I have a method which returns "HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT" and HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR .But looks like HttpStatus is deprecated in spring6.x so how can i handle this issue. While building project with HttpStatus getting CE as "incompatible types: HttpStatusCode cannot be converted to HttpStatus"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change it to return an HttpStatusCode instead, e.g.

```
return HttpStatusCode.valueOf(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT.value());
```

HttpStatusCode is an interface that could represent any 3-digit integer, while HttpStatus can only enumerate limited values.