# HttpStatusCode in Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-status-codes

I just migrated an application to Spring Boot 3 and before the migration I used HttpStatus to obtain more details about the error message that a certain web client returned with the gerReasonPhrase() method.

Now I find that in Spring Boot 3, HttpStatus is deprecated and I have to use HttpStatusCode instead. But HttpStatusCode does not have the getReasonPhrase() method or anything similar. Is there a way to obtain the same information as before through HttpStatusCode without having to make a status code map with its corresponding messages?

I am searching a similar method in Spring Boot 3 than the one that exists in Spring Boot 2.

Comment: Which `HttpStatus` are you talking about? The class [`org.springframework.http.HttpStatus`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.1.2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html) (Spring Framework 6.1.2; e.g. Spring Boot 3.2.0 uses Spring Framework 6.1.1) doesn't seem to be deprecated. It might be a good idea to provide a [mre] of the code you're having problems with.

Comment: Also `HttpStatus` implements `HttpStatusCode` (and `HttpStatus` seems to be the only public implementation of `HttpStatusCode`), so maybe a conditional cast is sufficient to access it if you're calling some method that returns `HttpStatusCode` instead of `HttpStatus`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm copying the top part of this answer [Error Response body changed after Boot 3 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75029947/error-response-body-changed-after-boot-3-upgrade)

Spring Web 6 introduced support for the "Problem Details for HTTP APIs" specification, [RFC 7807](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807.html)

With this, the [ResponseStatusException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/ResponseStatusException.html) now implements the [ErrorResponse](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/ErrorResponse.html) interface and extends the [ErrorResponseException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/ErrorResponseException.html) class.

Having a quick look at the javadocs, we can see that all these are backed by the RFC 7807 formatted [ProblemDetail](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ProblemDetail.html) body, which, as you can imagine, has the fields of the new response you're getting, and also uses the application/problem+json media type in the response.

```
ResponseStatusException.getBody();
```

returns the [ProblemDetial](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ProblemDetail.html). In the javadoc for [setTitle](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ProblemDetail.html#setTitle(java.lang.String)), you'll see the value comes from  HttpStatus.getReasonPhrase().  So that's how you upgrade that part to spring-boot3.

```
HttpStatus.getReasonPhrase();
```

in spring-boot3 becomes

```
ResponseStatusException.getBody().getTitle();
```

Also, you can use that ProblemDetail object to get the status code

```
ResponseStatusException.getBody().getStatus();
```

Answer (score 0):

[HttpStatus](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html) don't seems to be deprecated in the current spring version.

But there are **some** of the enum values that are deprecated (ex. CHECKPOINT).

Also, `HttpStatus` actually implements `HttpStatusCode`, they are not two different implementations. And so you can pass status code between them since its the same [value](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatusCode.html#value()) field declared in `HttpStatusCode` ([see mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76719287/facing-issue-with-httpstatus-in-spring-boot-3))